# Apache2 shows blank page because of 000-default?

Tags: zend-framework, apache2

My situation got Zend Framework involved.

My 000-default looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zend/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /var/www/html/zend/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Whenever I am trying to use the following urls:

```
http://localhost
http://localhost/index.php
http://localhost/sdfkljdsflkjsddlsfkjsd
```

I am getting a blank page.

When I create a new php file with "echo phpinfo();", it's working fine.

So is there something wrong with my 000-default file or is there anything else that might cause this problem?

Comment: You can't see anything in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file?

Comment: Ugh, I didn't consider that because I am losing my nerves here for a couple of days because I can't get things running. Anyway, I am adding what I found in the error.log in my post in a few seconds.

Comment: what version of apache are you using? In my projects with apache 2.4 we need to add the "Require all granted" directive in the "Directory" section, if you use 2.2 it doesn't matter

Comment: @AndreaManzi It's "Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)". I already solved it. Thanks. I forgot to the check the error log before I posted here.

Comment: However if in your project you have the file composer.json you can use "composer install" for dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was blinded by my rage, so here's what happened.

After I looked in the error log, I found these lines:

```
[Sun Aug 18 17:42:00.448057 2019] [:error] [pid 17126] [client 127.0.0.1:45934] PHP Warning:  require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/zend/public/index.php on line 18
[Sun Aug 18 17:42:00.448116 2019] [:error] [pid 17126] [client 127.0.0.1:45934] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/zend/library:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/zend/public/index.php on line 18
```

I copied the Zend Library to /usr/share/ZendFramework-1.12.20/ because it was recommended somewhere. And yet my local project had to know about the library, so I placed a softlink to that folder.

Previously I was so smart and copied THE WHOLE folder (with /bin, etc.) into the local project's library folder.

It's working now. Learning from mistakes never felt so good.